# Java Query SQL to JSON returns only one row

Tags: java, sql, json

I am creating a webservice to query a database and return the data to JSON format for an Ajax call.

All is good until I try to return more than one row from my SQL database, my result then is

```
{"tag":"Ingredients","Items":"flour     ","Quantity":"6         "}
```

Note the spaces after the items and quantity tags, so I printed the query results to my console and realized that it is returning a multi-line result.

i tried to remove line breaks in case that was the issue but it did not seem to work.

Here is my JSON converter Utility.java

```
public static String constructSQLJSON(String tag, String string, String string2) {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        String sqlout = null;
        try {
            obj.put("tag", tag);
            obj.put("Items", new String(string));
            obj.put("Quantity", new String(string2));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
        return obj.toString();
    }
```

And my DB_probe.java

```
    while (rs.next()) {
        String items = rs.getString(1);
         items = items.replaceAll("\n ", " ").replaceAll("\n", " ");
        String Quantity = rs.getString(2);
         ingred = Utitlity.constructSQLJSON("Ingredients", items, Quantity);
        System.out.println( rs.getString(1) + rs.getString(2));

    }
```

I am using the codehaus.jettison.json package

Edit: I am using postman to test the results

Comment: Where did you get the response from in your JSON? There are a lot of factors that can make this happen to your code and please post enough code so we can take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

If you suspect like that. you can trim String. try as follows

```
obj.put("Items", new String(string.trim()));
obj.put("Quantity", new String(string2.trim()));
```

Comment: That removed the extra space at the end but did not return the additional rows

Comment: use JSONARRAY. add your objects one by one finally you return it

Comment: JSONArray objarr= new JSONArray();
objarr.put(obj);

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for an example:

```
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonArrayBuilder;
import javax.json.JsonValue;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Class {
  public JsonValue constructSQLJSON(String tag,
                                           String string,
                                           String string2) {
    return Json.createObjectBuilder()
      .add("tag", tag)
      .add("Items", string.trim())
      .add("Quantity", string2.trim())
      .build();
  }

  public String someMethod() throws SQLException {
    final ResultSet rs = null;//..get result set...
    final JsonArrayBuilder results = Json.createArrayBuilder();
    while (rs.next()) {
      results.add(constructSQLJSON(
        "Ingredients",
        rs.getString(1),
        rs.getString(2)));
    }
    return results.build().toString();
  }
}
```